# Fill up string of binary digits until certain length is reached

Tags: python

I have a string of ones and zeros, which typically has a length of 8*n, since they come from "n" bytes.
Now I want to arrange them into groups of five and I want to fill up the string with "0" until there are 16 5-bit "bytes" in total.

This is what I came up with but I can't figure out why this is not working.

```
while(len(binary_i) // (5*16) != 0):
    binary_i = binary_i + "0"
```

Comment: Don't you need to use `%` instead of `//`?

Comment: case closed .. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that you're using `//` instead of `%`. Also, if you want to use a Python built-in alternative instead of using this while loop, try this:

```
binary_i.ljust(5*16, '0')  # Fill `binary_i` using `0` up to 5*16 characters
```

Comment: You're right, I mixed it up. Thanks @martineau